# listas anidadas en un json Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

### De la siguiente consulta:

```
select jsonb from table
```

---

### obtengo el siguiente json:

```
{"question": false, 
    "contact": {"name_contact": "", "email_contact": ""}, 
    "queson_two": {"ques_two": {"condition": {"402": false, "403": false}}}, 
    "questions_three": {"pregunta": true, "pregunta_a": false}, 
    "EMPRESA": [{"code": 391, "response": "NO"},
                {"code": 392, "response": "2020-05-15 00:00:00"}, 
                {"code": 393, "response": "APROBADO"}], 
    "version": "2.99"}
```

---

quisiera obtener solo un dato de los campos que se encuentran dentro del campo  "EMPRESA"

```
{"code": 391, "response": "NO"}
```

ó

```
{"code": 392, "response": "2020-05-15 00:00:00"}
```

alguien q conozca el método por favor para después obtener los valores internos, o alguna documentación

Answer (score 0):

Puedes consultar la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) de PostgreSQL, respecto a los operadores y funciones de los tipos de datos `JSON` y `JSONB`

te adelanto que en tu caso puedes utilizar el operador `->` para obtener los datos del campo `EMPRESA` y eso te va a retornar un arreglo `JSON` en el cual puedes obtener el valor que requieras usando el indice requerido:

```
SELECT j->'EMPRESA'->0 as pri ,j->'EMPRESA'->1 as seg,j->'EMPRESA'->2 as ter FROM 

(

SELECT '{"question": false, 
    "contact": {"name_contact": "", "email_contact": ""}, 
    "queson_two": {"ques_two": {"condition": {"402": false, "403": false}}}, 
    "questions_three": {"pregunta": true, "pregunta_a": false}, 
    "EMPRESA": [{"code": 391, "response": "NO"},
                {"code": 392, "response": "2020-05-15 00:00:00"}, 
                {"code": 393, "response": "APROBADO"}], 
    "version": "2.99"}'::jsonb as j ) dat;

               pri               |                       seg                        |                  ter                  
---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 {"code": 391, "response": "NO"} | {"code": 392, "response": "2020-05-15 00:00:00"} | {"code": 393, "response": "APROBADO"}
(1 row)
```

en el sitio de la documentación podras encontrar otras funciones que pueden ayudarte a *parsear* tu datos `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

Como alternativa a la anterior respuesta, podrias probar la siguiente consulta:

```
select tabla1.row1
    from(
        select  json_array_elements(tabla."your_row_name" -> 'EMPRESA')  as  row1
        from "your_table_name" tabla ) tabla1
where tabla1.row1::jsonb @> '{"code":392}'
```

La subconsulta extrae el arreglo de objetos que tienen "key : 'EMPRESA' ", la consulta final toma ese arreglo y muestra aquellos elementos con "code":392.